# faster way to count row from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any other way to retrieve faster the total records from another table.

This my sample sql code:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT count(*) from table1 where table1.field2 = table2.field1 AND table1.status ='value1') as total1,
  (SELECT count(*) from table1 where table1.field2 = table2.field1 AND table1.status ='value2') as total2
FROM table2
```

Comment: To retrieve a count of records based on a condition, MySQL needs to 1) find the records that satisfy the condition and 2) increase the counter for each record found. To find the records, it has to perform I/O. I/O for scanning the index and I/O for scanning the disk. Therefore, if this operation is slow, it's due to your server's I/O subsystem. You can try rewriting your query, but the bottom line is - work will be done and the weakest link in this chain will be I/O subsystem (no, you can't rewrite this query to run faster, it's fine as it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find counts for each field in subquery and left join it with the table2

```
select t.*, a.total1, a.total2
from table2 t
left join (
    select field2, sum(status = 'value1') total1, sum(status = 'value2') total2
    from table1
    group by field2
) a on t.field1 = a.field2
```

Comment: Note that the `group by` condition and `on` conditions are wrong for the first subquery.

Comment: thanks for this one, the  Query just took 0.3740 seconds. its a very big help

Comment: @Jaycel Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Under many circumstances, you approach is fine:

```
SELECT t2.*,
       (SELECT count(*) from table1 t1 where t1.field2 = t2.field1 AND t1.status = 'value1') as total1,
       (SELECT count(*) from table1 t1 where t1.field2 = t2.field1 AND t1.status = 'value2') as total2
FROM table2 t2;
```

For performance, you want an index on `table1(field2, status)`.

An alternative is to pre-aggregate `table1`:

```
select t2.*, t1.total1, t1.total2
from table2 t2 left join
     (select t1.field2, sum(status = 'value1') as total1, sum(status = 'value2') as total2
      from table1 t1
      group by t1.field2
     ) t1
     on t2.field1 = t1.field2;
```

This would have better performance under some conditions.

Which works better depends on the data.  For instance, if `table2` has 1 row and `table1` has 1,000,000 rows with 5 matching `table2`, then the first is better.

If `table2` is larger than `table1`, then the second method is probably better.

Comment: my problem is that it take almost 30 seconds before i get all the records. is there any other way to retrieve the data faster?

Comment: @JaycelCunanan . . . Add the appropriate indexes.

Comment: @JaycelCunanan - don't `SELECT * FROM table2`? You're retrieving the counts **AND** everything in `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood but isn't it the same like

```
SELECT table1.status,
       count(*)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field2 = t2.field1
WHERE table1.status IN ('value1',
                        'value2')
GROUP BY table1.status
```